# dmesg is not logging anything

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

logs printed by dmesg is not updated since two months ago even we have many process killed by OOM in last week.

what is dmesg source and how can I find if the system log is working?

dmesg output:

```
[Mon Jul  6 21:56:27 2015] 736kB, rss:156kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 11:11:43 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 15935 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:156kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 11:11:43 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 5898 (python) score 0 vm:1122780kB, rss:1063096kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:13 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 3840 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:152kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:13 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 3841 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:156kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:13 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6502 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:168kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:13 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6504 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:220kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:14 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6506 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:328kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:14 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6508 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:348kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:50:14 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6491 (python) score 0 vm:993704kB, rss:934084kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:51:29 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6510 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:276kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:51:29 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6512 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:276kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:51:29 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6534 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:320kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:51:29 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6536 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:316kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:51:29 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6525 (python) score 0 vm:992252kB, rss:932812kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6538 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:276kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6540 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:280kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6576 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:284kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6578 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:360kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6580 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:332kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6582 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:320kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6584 (getty) score 0 vm:6428kB, rss:356kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6586 (getty) score 0 vm:6428kB, rss:440kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6588 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:372kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6589 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:404kB, swap:0kB
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] OOM killer in rage, 1 tasks killed
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] OOM killer in rage, 1 tasks killed
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:09 2016] OOM killer in rage, 1 tasks killed
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:10 2016] OOM killer in rage, 1 tasks killed
[Fri Feb 26 13:52:10 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 1126 (beam.smp) score 0 vm:2922908kB, rss:508796kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 09:48:26 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6593 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:156kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 09:48:26 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6597 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:148kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 09:48:26 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 4354 (python) score 0 vm:2192548kB, rss:2056640kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 13:57:25 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 11648 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:160kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 13:57:25 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 11649 (getty) score 0 vm:12736kB, rss:152kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 13:57:25 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 6599 (cron) score 0 vm:23604kB, rss:232kB, swap:0kB
[Sun Feb 28 13:57:25 2016] Out of memory in UB 6547: OOM killed process 30284 (java) score 0 vm:3811464kB, rss:463996kB, swap:0kB
```

it seems server times was wrong (2016) for some period (I don't know why), but it's fixed now:

```
ali@server:~$ date
Mon Aug 31 04:14:05 EDT 2015
```

Answer (score 5):

What is dmesg source: dmesg read logs stored in kernel buffer which log_buf.
dmesg reads printk buffer at once and dumps it on shell.

cat /proc/kmsg can be used to see if logs are getting stored in printk buffer, which keeps reading printk logs as they are stored.

But as you have you tried kill process last week and its showing those logs in dmesg so I will suggest you check date and time setting of system .